# How do display gallery attached to the custom post type

Tags: wordpress, gallery, custom-post-type

I have a custom post 'event'.
For each post there is a gallery attached. On a main galley page i am displaying featured images from each post . Now i want that when person clicks on this featured image , he should be taken to a new template where images from the attached gallery of the post are displayed using get_post_gallery().
I can use permalink because it will take me to the 'single-event'.

How can i do it ? Please help me out.

Comment: So you want to redirect the user to the gallery when he clicks the featured image?

Comment: Yup this is what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

One way is to install a plugin called [Page Links To](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/). Basically you install the plugin, activate it then go to your media files. In the bottom you will see a section which will ask you:

Point this content to:

1. Its normal WordPress URL
2. A custom URL

Pick the second option and enter the desired URL.

You can enter the desired URL in another way aswell. When you add an image to a post, an options tree shows up. Somewhere are URL settings. Feel free to check that out too. In my opinion that plugins makes it so easy to use and redirect.

Comment: Can you give me little more information , Like what would be the  name of the  php file where  i will  have the code for getting the gallery and displaying it .                                                          And what would be the custom url that i will have to use

Comment: You don't need to put that in the php file. Just make a new page or post or whatever. Then add the gallery through the editor. Isn't that easier? Or does it have to be written in code?

Comment: But then i'll have to create a new page/post other than my current custom post   and then add gallery . I am already having the gallery in my custom post.                                                            Or i am not getting you , sorry if so.